# Handlebars bind a dynamic object property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

When using Ember and Handlebars, is it possible to bind (two-way) a dynamically determined property of an object.

`{{input value=field[field_name_var]}}`

instead of the statically determined style

`{{input value=field.field_name}}`

I have tried:

`{{input value=(get field field_name_var)}}`

but that only results in a one way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exact usecase is documented here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_binding-dynamic-attribute